# Evaluate string values in a single column (mysql)

Tags: mysql

I have a field that contains data like below:

```
124.97#54.03#5#16
```

its number which separated by '#'. I want to sum these number, but not get the result yet.

First I use this query to replace '#' with '+' sign.

```
select replace(myfieldname,'#','+') from mytable
```

I imagine if there's a function 'eval' like in PHP, it should be done.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Note: It's ok if you can help me to separate that single column to multiple column in result, actually that's better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

>
*Note: It's ok if you can help me to separate that single column to multiple column in result, actually that's better.*

Try this query -

```
SELECT
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(column1, '#', 1) v1,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(column1, '#', 2), '#', -1) v2,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(column1, '#', 3), '#', -1) v3
  ...
  ...
  ...
FROM table_name;
```

**Another variant:**

```
SET @values = '124.97#54.03#5#16';
SET @values = REPLACE(@values, '#', '+');
SET @select = CONCAT('SELECT ', @values);

PREPARE stmt FROM @select;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```